# What is a word to describe a person who wears several masks?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word best describes a person who is deceitful and very complicated to understand? As they say, he wears several masks.

Comment: There are probably many ways to describe such a person, but I might start with _enigmatic_ or _mysterious_.

Comment: Wearing several masks and being very complicated to understand are two very different things. Clarify, please.

Comment: @J.R.: "That's his power?  He's *mysterious*?"

Comment: @chaos: I made my initial comment before the question was edited, when it asked for ways to describe "a person who is not straightforward but very complicated as he wears several masks." I also initially missed your cultural reference, but I got it now :^)

Answer (score 6):

Some words related to *[deceitful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deceitful)* are *[duplicitous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duplicitous)* ("Given to or marked by deliberate deceptiveness in behavior or speech"),  *[double dealing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/double-dealing)* ("Cheating, dishonest; treacherous"), and aforementioned *[two-faced](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two-faced)* ("deceitful, hypocritical or duplicitous").  Analogous to previously-mentioned *[multifaceted](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multifaceted)* is *[many-sided](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/many-sided)*, meaning "Having many aspects".

Answer (score 3):

The common English idiom nearest to your meaning is to speak of such a person as **two-faced**, though this strictly means someone is deceitful.  To describe someone who is complex and hard to understand without implying deceitfulness, we might call them **multifaceted**.

Answer (score 2):

Wearing several masks and being very complicated to understand are two very different things.

If you are after a word to describe someone who is very complicated to understand because they change often, then I like [**fickle**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fickle?q=fickle) or, perhaps a bit more metaphorically, [**volatile**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/volatile?q=volatile).

For someone who wears several masks, there are other answers on this page which I quite like.

Answer (score 1):

You may say the person has multiple personalities, or is dissociated. If the person changes according to the ambience you could call him/her "chameleon".

Comment: *[Voluble](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voluble)* most commonly means "fluent or having a ready flow of speech", and while it has a couple of rare senses that might apply, I suspect you mean *[volatile](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/volatile)*, meaning "fickle" or "temporary or ephemeral".

Comment: @jwpat7 I guess you are right, though it seems that 'voluble' may be used in the sense of something that changes easily, there was some confusion between dictionaries (portuguese-english), as the words "voluble" and "volúvel" share the meaning of "turning easily on an axis", the portuguese word does not mean "fluent" and mostly means "unstable, inconstant". Thanks.