# What's single word for fake image?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is single word in English for a fake/false image (in terms of personality, not in terms of photograph) of someone?

Comment: Please can you add in an example sentence to show how you would use the word?

Answer (score 5):

*[Facade](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/facade)* ("A deceptive outward appearance") may suit.  Also consider *[disguise](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disguise?view=uk)*, *[persona](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/persona?view=uk)* ("a role or character adopted by an author or an actor"),  and *[masquerade](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/masquerade)* ("Acting or living under false pretenses; concealment of something by a false or unreal show; pretentious show; disguise").
*[Trumpery](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trumpery)* ("worthless finery; bric-a-brac or junk") may be used in achieving a false image; by analogy one might call a false personality trumpery.  Spelling note: Be careful not to leave out the *er* before *y*.

You may also find useful words (such as *two-faced*, *Janus-like*, *deceiver*, *fake*, *double-dealer*, *duplicitous*, *polymorph*, *chameleon*, *wolf in sheep's clothing*, *poser*, *duplicitous*, *back-stabber*, *hypocrite*, *fraud*, *imposter*, *poseur*, *whited sepulcher*, *Devil in disguise*, *fool's gold*, *mirage*, *simulacrum*, et al) in answers to the following questions:

> • [#24216](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24216/a-good-noun-for-a-two-faced-person): "I'm in need of a word that describes someone who has two personalities (they don't necessarily contrast each other, good/evil)."
>   • [#72916](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72916/what-is-a-word-to-describe-a-person-who-wears-several-masks) "What word best describes a person who is deceitful and very complicated to understand? As they say, he wears several masks."
>   • [#42404](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42404/what-is-an-idiom-slang-for-someone-who-pretends-to-be-good-when-theyre-not) "A character in the movie is really bad, but when she talks with others, she pretends to be an innocent/ good woman. I want to know how to describe this kind of person."
>   • [#71398](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71398/common-phrases-for-something-that-appears-good-but-is-actually-bad) "What are common phrases that describe something that appears good but is actually bad?"

Answer (score 2):

How about *[beguile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beguile)*:

> *transitive verb*
> : to lead by deception
>
> *intransitive verb*
> : to deceive by wiles

or *[specious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specious)*:

> 2: having deceptive attraction or allure
> 3: having a false look of
> truth or genuineness : sophistic

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the semantic of the fakery/falsehood:

For someones personality I would suggest: ( in order )

1. Disingenuous
2. Phony
3. Factitious
4. Hypocritical
5. Artificial
6. Two Faced
7. Jive Turkey